# Social Studio integration with Sales Cloud

Tags: sales-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, social

few days ago I started to work with Social Studio and I was wondering if it is possibile to "connect" Sales Cloud with Social Studio.
I found documentaion only about Service Cloud and I'm not able to understand if it is possibile to enable Social Customer Service also on Sales cloud, I don't see this feature in setup menu, maybe I will have to log a case in Salesforce Support.
Anyone could help?
Thanks in advance
Alessia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue,if someone will face that here the solution: it has been necessary to log a case in Support to enable CSC feature. I would notify also that my client has Sales Cloud but he has Service Cloud licenses too.